# Django authentication issues

Tags: django, session, cookies

I run an ecommerce website on Django 2.1.0

I have some user session issues.

My checkout process is like so :
- Cart
- Delivery Info
- Summary
- Leaving the site for the bank for payment
- "**Notification**" Bank send a post resquest with payement informations
- If everything ok we redirect user to `/confirmation`

Problem is I noticed that users are no more logged in in "**Notification**" step.
On this step I have the decorator `@login_required`.
So it redirects user to `/my-account/login?next=/notification`
By the time user get redirected, he is logged in again.
So is redirected back to `/my-account/` and never visit `/confirmation` page.

The question is, why my user is disconnected on **notification**.

This setup use to work well for months.
I suspect django update from 1x to 2x ?
Is there known issue with session ?

Comment: Can you share view ? Is there anything going on inside of it ?

Comment: Hi, yes I can share the view, here it is https://gist.github.com/ValentinCreative/997e9fb51c404f1743284aa207ed662a
But i think the problem is not related to the view itself, because decorator `@login_required` doesn't let user in it

Comment: I would put `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and see on what line user is getting logged out. That could be a start.